# SQL calculating multiple columns and comparing its result with a category

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the table with three columns in the result column i multiplied **weight** with **past seven days** to show the **result**, there is another category beside this table that i want to show only one of the three category if the grant total match with the that i wrote some code that for now can multiple and sum the score in one column but i want to know can change this code to compare with the category as well.

[image: Example]

on the box in the picture as you see there are three categories with the level column in the name of interpretation.

what i want is as you see **total** in the left box is 56.5 now it match with **> 42.5** value in the right box i want that my sql code give me below result.

```
Score      Category        Interpretation
56.5       >42.5             High
```

i did try below code i need to bright some changes on it i think, currently i don't have another specific table for the three category in the right box in the picture, if possible to achieve above result without creating a table for category it would be good if not still fine with me to create another table and join, please show me the way

```
select (SUM (FCS_CEREALS_AND_TUBERS * 2) + SUM (FCS_PULSES * 3) +
        SUM (FCS_VEGETABLES * 1) + SUM (FCS_FRUIT * 1)  +
        SUM (FCS_MEAT_AND_FISH * 4) + SUM (FCS_MILK * 4) +
        SUM (FCS_SUGAR * 0.5) + SUM (FCS_OIL * 0.5)) AS RESULT
from TBL_FCS
```

Comment: Tag your database name.

Comment: Oracle apex SQL command

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have pivoted data. If in your original table data is unpivoted then work on this table. Here is the solution with your current structure:

```
with 
  weights(id, food_group, weight) as (
    select 1, 'CEREALS AND TUBERS', 2 from dual union all
    select 2, 'PULSES',             3 from dual union all
    select 3, 'VEGETABLES',         1 from dual union all
    select 4, 'FRUIT',              1 from dual union all
    select 5, 'MEAT AND FISH',      4 from dual union all
    select 6, 'MILK',               4 from dual union all
    select 7, 'SUGAR',             .5 from dual union all 
    select 8, 'OIL',               .5 from dual ) 
select food_group, past_7_days, weight, result, 
       case when id is null and result <= 28 then 'Low'
            when id is null and result between 28.5 and 42 then 'Normal'
            when id is null and result >= 42.5 then 'High'
       end as interpretation
  from (
    select food_group, past_7_days, weight, sum(past_7_days * weight) result, id
      from (
        select *
          from tbl_fcs
          unpivot (past_7_days for food_group in (
            fcs_cereals_and_tubers as 'CEREALS AND TUBERS', 
            fcs_pulses             as 'PULSES', 
            fcs_vegetables         as 'VEGETABLES', 
            fcs_fruit              as 'FRUIT', 
            fcs_meat_and_fish      as 'MEAT AND FISH', 
            fcs_milk               as 'MILK', 
            fcs_sugar              as 'SUGAR', 
            fcs_oil                as 'OIL')))
      join weights using (food_group)
      group by rollup((food_group, past_7_days, weight, id)))
   order by id
```

**<sup>[demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108471/sql-calculating-multiple-columns-and-comparing-its-result-with-a-category)</sup>**

You have to unpivot values for each food group, then join with their weights and multiply. Add group by rollup and conditional interpretation using `case when`.